# heroku-container-registry is blacklisted

Tags: docker, heroku, heroku-cli

[This Heroku + Docker example](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda) suggests to run:

```
 $ heroku plugins:install heroku-container-registry
```

When I run above command,  the result is:

```
 »   Error: heroku-container-registry is blacklisted
```

What does it mean to be blacklisted; is the technology obsolete? Can I workaround it?

*See @Chris solution below. After @Chris taught me I did not need `heroku plugins:install`, I tried the next steps*
 For future reference, I ran into a series of other errors. In the Heroku  error during connect:

```
Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine:
The system cannot find the file specified. 
In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. 
This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

So then I tried to run Docker Desktop for Windows, got Docker error, [will follow these instructions](https://superuser.com/q/1382472/292784)

> Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in BIOS. [See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled)

Comment: Do you need a docker based application to your heroku account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is the technology obsolete?

No, but that document is. The [`heroku-container-registry` code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-container-registry) has been merged into the [main Heroku CLI](https://github.com/heroku/cli). You should be able to [use it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) without installing any plugins.

Try running the second command listed in that tutorial to get started:

```
heroku container:login
```

Comment: This also worked for me, is it any different? 
`heroku plugins:install @heroku-cli/heroku-container-registry`

Comment: @TheRedPea, if your Heroku CLI is up to date I don't think that should be necessary. But with an old client maybe it works (though in that case I'd recommend updating the CLI itself).